# Unable to open some websites but Internet is working fine

Tags: windows-vista, internet

From my browser I am able to use Google Search, but am unable to open Gmail, Yahoo Mail and some other sites. However Stack Overflow and Super User links are working fine.

I am using Windows Vista and BSNL broadband connection. I've tried browsing from Firefox and Internet Explorer but get the same results.

What's the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a tracert, and see if it is just bombing out somewhere along the route as I suspect.

Try this at a command prompt:

`tracert yahoo.com` (or whatever the actual site is)

Look at the results. If it got out through a number of routers, then starts giving you a *, the best thing you can do is wait for it to resolve itself. If it persists, you can call your ISP, and ask them to contact the owners of the routers in question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Google *search* works, but Google *mail* doesn't I'd be guessing that something is interfering with the HTTPS port 443.  Are there any other sites with secure login pages you can try to verify this?

Most modern web-mail sites will force you over to https.